# .NET MVC application fails to load every second time in IE but fine in every other browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, https, server, webserver

I have a .NET MVC application installed on a windows 2008 server running with HTTPS.
The web site works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari but experiences sporadic behaviour in IE. Here are some of the symptoms:

- Page loads only every second time. All other times it displays the following message:[image]
  (The page loads over HTTPS)
- Ajax form submit with file uploads fail every second time

To make matters more interesting, there is also a PHP application on this server also which happens to load fine 3-20 times in a row before it displays the message above. Also, if i leave it for about 3 minutes and then refresh, the above error displays. Again this happens in IE only

Comment: The error message contains your "fix"? You need to set IE settings -> advanced to explicitly use the TLS protocol (probably set at SSL 3.0) - re: the site/server is restricting SSL connections to those protocols. Odd that it works "sometimes" though, so perhaps there's more to it (load balanced where restrictions aren't synced?)

Comment: That works but.... the question is, can i make it work without having to manually change the setting?

Comment: TLS is pretty much the "base" level these days - that's why the [_other browsers_ work](https://www.ssl.com/how-to/turn-off-ssl-3-0-and-tls-1-0-in-your-browser/) without tinkering with settings.

Comment: Ok that sounds good enough to me. I find it interesting that by default, the SLL 3.0 setting in IE's options was unchecked by default. In any case, if you post your suggestion as an answer, i will accept it